# import the full file in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two files in my react app one called App.jsx and the second one called ProfileData [image: Files]

there is a map function Called (Feed) in ProfileData.jsx I want to export it and run it in App.jsx when I try to export the function I got an Error [image: The Error I got]

this is the App.jsx code

```html
import React, { useState , useEffect} from "react";
import { AuthenticatedTemplate, UnauthenticatedTemplate, useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { loginRequest } from "./authConfig";
import { PageLayout } from "./components/PageLayout";
import { ProfileData,Feed } from "./components/ProfileData";
import { callMsGraph,PostData } from "./graph";
import { TimeSheet } from "./components/fullpage";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import "./styles/App.css";
import "./styles/TimeSheet.css";
import { RefreshTokenClient } from "@azure/msal-common";

/**
 * Renders information about the signed-in user or a button to retrieve data about the user
 */


<ProfileData/>





export var Title = "";
export var Date = "";
export var Hours = "";
export var ActivityType = "";



function support(){
    Title = "Support";
    Date = "8/11/2022";
    Hours="5";
    ActivityType="Support";
}


const ProfileContent = () => {
    const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
    const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState(null);
    const [graphDatah, setGraphDatah] = useState(null);

    function RequestProfileData() {
        console.log("TEST")
        // Silently acquires an access token which is then attached to a request for MS Graph data
        instance.acquireTokenSilent({
            ...loginRequest,
            account: accounts[0]
        }).then((response) => {
            callMsGraph(response.accessToken).then(response => setGraphData(response));
        });

        console.log(graphData);
    }

 //--------------------------

    function takesheet() {
        // Silently acquires an access token which is then attached to a request for MS Graph data
        instance.acquireTokenSilent({
            account: accounts[0]
        }).then((response) => {
            PostData(response.accessToken).then(response => { setGraphDatah(response);RequestProfileData();});
        });
    }


    useEffect(()=>{RequestProfileData()},[])


    function runAll()  {
        
    takesheet();
    Feed();

    }


   // console.log(graphData);

    return (
        <>
        
            <h5 className="card-title">Welcome {accounts[0].name}</h5>
            
            {graphData ? 
                
                <ProfileData graphData={graphData} />
              
              

                
                :
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={RequestProfileData}>Load Bapco ITD TimeSheet</Button>





                
            }


<AuthenticatedTemplate>

 
<div className="allbuttons">
      <button    className="supportrectangle-button" />
      <img onClick={runAll}  className="supportshape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png" />
      <b  className="support-b">Support</b>


      <button className="trainingrectangle-button" />
      <img className="trainingshape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png" />
      <b className="training-b">Training</b>

      <button className="operationsrectangle-button" />
      <img className="operationsshape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png" />
      <b className="operations-b">Operations</b>


      <button className="managmentrectangle-button" />
      <img className="managmentshape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png" />
      <b className="managment-b">Managment</b>


      <button className="absencerectangle-button" />
      <img className="absenceshape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png" />
      <b className="absence">Absence</b>


      <button className="governancerectangle-button" />
      <img className="governanceshape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png" />
      <b className="governance-b">Governance</b>


      <button className="administarationrectangle-button" />
      <img className="administaration-shape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png"/>
      <b className="administaration-b">Administaration</b>


      <button className="projectsrectangle-button" />
      <img className="projectsshape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png" />
      <b className="projects-b">Projects</b>
      </div>
      </AuthenticatedTemplate>
        </>
        
    );
};

/**
 * If a user is authenticated the ProfileContent component above is rendered. Otherwise a message indicating a user is not authenticated is rendered.
 */
const MainContent = () => {    
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <AuthenticatedTemplate>
                <ProfileContent />
            </AuthenticatedTemplate>
         
            <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
                <h5 className="card-title">Please sign-in to see your ITD TimeSheet platfourm.</h5>
            </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        </div>
    );
};

export default function App() {
    return (
        <PageLayout>
            <MainContent />
            

        </PageLayout>
    );
}
```

and this is the ProfileData.jsx

```html
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "../styles/TimeSheet.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import Moment from 'moment';
import { filter } from "lodash";
import {PostData} from "../graph"
import { graphConfig,graphConfigh } from "../authConfig";




/**
 * Renders information about the user obtained from MS Graph
 * @param props 
 */


 var todaydate = Date();

 var formated = Moment(todaydate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
 console.log(formated);



//Hours Change


//Hours Change
//Map function is here --------------------------------------.
/** 
function Feed(props) {

  {
    return (
      <>
        
         {props.data.map(item=>  ( 

         <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
          <div className="taskcolorback-div" />
          <button className="taskcolor-button" />

          <input className="tasktext-b" defaultValue={Moment(item.fields.Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}></input>
          <button className="taskwhite-button" />
          
          <b className="timeinline">{item.fields.Hours}Hr</b>
          <img className="vector-icon" alt="" src="icons8-chevron-right-64.png" />
          </React.Fragment>
          )) }
      </>
    ) 
  }
}
*/



export function Feed(props) { 
 const [data,setdata] = useState(props)

 
  return (
    <div>
      {props.data.map((item) => {
       var spFormated = Moment(item.fields.Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
        if (formated == spFormated ) {
          if(item.fields.Hours<=2){
            return(
            <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
              <div className="taskcolorback-div" />
              <button className="taskcolor-button" />
              <input className="tasktext-b" defaultValue={Moment(item.fields.Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}></input>
              <button className="taskwhite-button" />
              <b className="timeinline">{item.fields.Hours}Hr</b>
              <img className="vector-icon" alt="" src="icons8-chevron-right-64.png" />
            </React.Fragment>)
          }
         else if(item.fields.Hours==3){
            return( 
            <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
              <div className="taskcolorback-div3" />
              <button className="taskcolor-button3" />
              <input className="tasktext-b3" defaultValue={Moment(item.fields.Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}></input>
              <button className="taskwhite-button3" />
              <b className="timeinline3">{item.fields.Hours}Hr</b>
              <img className="vector-icon3" alt="" src="icons8-chevron-right-64.png" />
            </React.Fragment>)
          }
          else if(item.fields.Hours==4){
            return(
            <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
              <div className="taskcolorback-div4" />
              <button className="taskcolor-button4" />
              <input className="tasktext-b4" defaultValue={Moment(item.fields.Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}></input>
              <button className="taskwhite-button4" />
              <b className="timeinline4">{item.fields.Hours}Hr</b>
              <img className="vector-icon4" alt="" src="icons8-chevron-right-64.png" />
            </React.Fragment>)
          }
          else if(item.fields.Hours>=5){
            return(             
            <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
              <div className="taskcolorback-div5" />
              <button className="taskcolor-button5" />
              <input className="tasktext-b5" defaultValue={Moment(item.fields.Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}></input>
              <button className="taskwhite-button5" />
              <b className="timeinline5">{item.fields.Hours}Hr</b>
              <img className="vector-icon5" alt="" src="icons8-chevron-right-64.png" />
            </React.Fragment>)
          }
          return(
          <> 
         <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
          <div className="taskcolorback-div" />
          <button className="taskcolor-button" />
          <input className="tasktext-b" defaultValue={Moment(item.fields.Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}></input>
          <button className="taskwhite-button" />
          <b className="timeinline">{item.fields.Hours}Hr</b>
          <img className="vector-icon" alt="" src="icons8-chevron-right-64.png" />
        </React.Fragment>  
         </>
      )
        }

        // ️ render nothing
        //return console.log("null");
        null
      })}
    </div>
  );
}


//------------------------------------




export const ProfileData = (props) => {
//const array1 = props.graphData.value;
 const [array1,setarray1]=useState(props.graphData.value);            
const [hours,sethours]=useState(2);




    return (
<div>
<div id="profile-div"/>
      <div className="timesheet-div">
      <div className="background-div" />
      <div className="leftbar-div" />
      <div className="rectangle-div" />
      <img className="bapco-logo16-1-icon" alt="" src="bapco-logo16-1@2x.png" />

      <Button className="HoursShape-button" variant="outline-primary" />
      
      
      <Button className="todayshape-button" variant="outline-primary" />
      <Button className="dateshape-button" variant="outline-primary" />
      <b className="today-b">Today</b>
      <b className="Date">{formated}</b>
      <b className="HN">{hours}</b>
      <b className="timeline-b">Timeline</b>
      <img className="HNPlus" onClick={()=>sethours(hours+1)}  alt="" src="icons8-plus-64.png" />
      <img className="HNMinus" onClick={()=>sethours(hours-1)} alt="" src="icons8-minus-64.png" />
      <div>
      <Feed data={array1}/>
      </div>

    </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

is there a possible way I can import (profileData.jsx) into (App.jsx) and run it?

Comment: In App.jsx you have used your profile data component remove it from there and try.

Comment: I removed profiledata and got an Error because there is functions called in App.jsx

Comment: Iam trying to run function Feed() from profileData.jsx into App.jsx

Comment: As I can see Feed is component so please try to call it in return based on your condition.

Comment: Can you please write it as a code ? so its correct I put it as an answer thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please remove profileData after import and use Feed inside return based on your condition if required.

```
import React, { useState , useEffect} from "react";
import { AuthenticatedTemplate, UnauthenticatedTemplate, useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { loginRequest } from "./authConfig";
import { PageLayout } from "./components/PageLayout";
import { ProfileData,Feed } from "./components/ProfileData";
import { callMsGraph,PostData } from "./graph";
import { TimeSheet } from "./components/fullpage";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import "./styles/App.css";
import "./styles/TimeSheet.css";
import { RefreshTokenClient } from "@azure/msal-common";

/**
 * Renders information about the signed-in user or a button to retrieve data about the user
 */

   

export var Title = "";
export var Date = "";
export var Hours = "";
export var ActivityType = "";



function support(){
    Title = "Support";
    Date = "8/11/2022";
    Hours="5";
    ActivityType="Support";
}


const ProfileContent = () => {
    const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
    const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState(null);
    const [graphDatah, setGraphDatah] = useState(null);

    function RequestProfileData() {
        console.log("TEST")
        // Silently acquires an access token which is then attached to a request for MS Graph data
        instance.acquireTokenSilent({
            ...loginRequest,
            account: accounts[0]
        }).then((response) => {
            callMsGraph(response.accessToken).then(response => setGraphData(response));
        });

        console.log(graphData);
    }

 //--------------------------

    function takesheet() {
        // Silently acquires an access token which is then attached to a request for MS Graph data
        instance.acquireTokenSilent({
            account: accounts[0]
        }).then((response) => {
            PostData(response.accessToken).then(response => { setGraphDatah(response);RequestProfileData();});
        });
    }


    useEffect(()=>{RequestProfileData()},[])


    function runAll()  {
        
    takesheet();

    }


   // console.log(graphData);

    return (
        <>
        // condition for feed data
       <Feed />
            <h5 className="card-title">Welcome {accounts[0].name}</h5>
            
            {graphData ? 
                
                <ProfileData graphData={graphData} />
              
              

                
                :
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={RequestProfileData}>Load Bapco ITD TimeSheet</Button>





                
            }


<AuthenticatedTemplate>

 
<div className="allbuttons">
      <button    className="supportrectangle-button" />
      <img onClick={runAll}  className="supportshape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png" />
      <b  className="support-b">Support</b>


      <button className="trainingrectangle-button" />
      <img className="trainingshape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png" />
      <b className="training-b">Training</b>

      <button className="operationsrectangle-button" />
      <img className="operationsshape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png" />
      <b className="operations-b">Operations</b>


      <button className="managmentrectangle-button" />
      <img className="managmentshape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png" />
      <b className="managment-b">Managment</b>


      <button className="absencerectangle-button" />
      <img className="absenceshape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png" />
      <b className="absence">Absence</b>


      <button className="governancerectangle-button" />
      <img className="governanceshape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png" />
      <b className="governance-b">Governance</b>


      <button className="administarationrectangle-button" />
      <img className="administaration-shape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png"/>
      <b className="administaration-b">Administaration</b>


      <button className="projectsrectangle-button" />
      <img className="projectsshape-icon" alt="" src="plus.png" />
      <b className="projects-b">Projects</b>
      </div>
      </AuthenticatedTemplate>
        </>
        
    );
};

/**
 * If a user is authenticated the ProfileContent component above is rendered. Otherwise a message indicating a user is not authenticated is rendered.
 */
const MainContent = () => {    
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <AuthenticatedTemplate>
                <ProfileContent />
            </AuthenticatedTemplate>
         
            <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
                <h5 className="card-title">Please sign-in to see your ITD TimeSheet platfourm.</h5>
            </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        </div>
    );
};

export default function App() {
    return (
        <PageLayout>
            <MainContent />
            

        </PageLayout>
    );
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: As you can see in code I have mentioned for condition add for data needed for Feed component and pass data as we are passing to component and then use those data as props, it should work